# Mixins Can't be Instantiated Error in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am trying to export the function `isDarkMode()` but I get the error "mixins can't be instantiated". The error happens in `_MainAppState<StatefulWidget> createState() => _MainAppState();` line after `createState() =>` .

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MainApp());
}

class MainApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MainApp({super.key});

  @override
  _MainAppState<StatefulWidget> createState() => _MainAppState(); //Error happens here
}

mixin _MainAppState <T extends StatefulWidget> on State<T> {
  isDarkMode() {
    return MediaQuery.of(context).platformBrightness;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp();
  }
}
```

Comment: i don't understand why you declare `_MainAppState` as a `mixin` not a `class`

Comment: I want to export isDarkMode() function to another class

Answer (score 2):

mixins can't be instantiated, so you need to create a class like below

```
class MyAppState extends State<MainApp> with _MainAppState<MainApp> {}
```

then initialize it in `MainApp`

```
class MainApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MainApp({super.key});

  @override
  _MainAppState<StatefulWidget> createState() => MyAppState(); //Error happens here
}
```